# How to get only current location coordinates if "allow once" in swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I have added three permissions in info.plist

and popup coming with three options.. here

1)if i click `"allow while using app"` then i need to autofill textfields with current location address but

2. **if i click `"allow once"` then i dont need to autofill textfields with current location**

in my code in both allow once and allow while using conditions textfields are autofilling with current location address:

```
 class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var latitude: String?
var logitude: String?
@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text3: UITextField!
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    
    let userLocation :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    latitude = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
    logitude = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print("error in reverseGeocode")
        }
        let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
       
        if placemark.count>0{
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
          
            let placemarkDictonary: NSDictionary=placemark.addressDictionary as! NSDictionary
            self.text1.text=placemarkDictonary["ZIP"] as? String
            self.text2.text=placemarkDictonary["City"] as? String
            self.text3.text=placemarkDictonary["Street"] as? String
        }
    }
    
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    myAnnotation.title = "Current location"
    mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
          switch status {
         
          case .denied:
              print("User hates you!!")

          case .authorizedWhenInUse:
              
               let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FinalViewController") as! FinalViewController
               self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);

          case .authorizedAlways:
              
              let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FinalViewController") as! FinalViewController
              self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);

          }
      }  
}
```

actually i need only current location coordinates when i click `"allow once"`, no need to autofill address in textfields. how to do that?

please help with code.

Comment: is there any way to do like this.. or not.. please suggest me somrthing

Answer (score 1):

`When In Use` and `Allow Once` are the same permission but with different expiry duration. Tapping `Allow Once` on the location permission prompt will enable `When In Use` permission for the current session of the app, ie. until the user force kills the app or if the app stays in the background for a long duration. If the user tapped `Allow Once` permission, you will get all location updates as if he gave `When In Use` permission. But if the user kills the app and relaunches it, the system will again show location permission prompt.

So what you are trying to do will not be possible by checking the status returned by `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization` as it will give the status as `authorizedWhenInUse` for both of these permissions. You can't differentiate them.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization)